# テーブルを複数結合した場合、enumの値で検索したときにstring -> integerがうまく変換されずにnullになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

主題の通り、テーブルを結合して、enumの値で検索したときにstring -> integerの変換がうまく行われない。to_sqlの結果をみると、nullに変換されてしまうのですが、どこが原因か特定できません。

- SQLクライアントなど通して、カラムのデータ型間違えていないか確認
- joinsすると起きてるようにみえる。
- self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabledは追加してある
- 結合したときに、他のテーブルにtypeカラムはない

解決方法ご存知であれば教えてほしいです。
尚、業務コードなので、ぼかしてかいてます。
（ぼかした結果タイポなどしていたら申し訳ないです。。。）

Rails 6.0.6.1
Ruby 2.7
PostgreSQL

ER図

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
class Employment
 belongs_to :account
end

class Account
 has_one :profile
 has_many :employments
end

class Profile
 has_one :career_verification, -> { where(type: AdminVerification::Type::CAREER) },
          class_name: 'AdminVerification', inverse_of: :profile, dependent: :destroy

 has_one :project_verification, -> { where(type: AdminVerification::Type::PROJECT) },
          class_name: 'AdminVerification', inverse_of: :profile, dependent: :destroy

 has_many :verifications, dependent: :destroy, class_name: 'AdminVerification'
end

class AdminVerification
 self.inheritance_column = :_type_disabled
 belongs_to :profile
 enum type: { project: 0, career: 10 }, _suffix: true

  module Type
    PROJECT = 'project'
    CAREER = 'career'
  end
end
```

#### 試したこと

```
# 今回実行したいクエリ
# type = NULLで検索されてしまう。
puts Employment.joins(account: { profile: :verifications }).where(admin_verifications: {type: "career"}).to_sql
 
SELECT "employments".* FROM "employments" 
INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "employments"."account_id" 
INNER JOIN "profiles" ON "profiles"."account_id" = "accounts"."id" 
INNER JOIN "admin_verifications" ON "admin_verifications"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" 
WHERE "admin_verifications"."type" = NULL

# enumのstringがちゃんと変換されているケース
puts AdminVerification.where(type: "career").to_sql
SELECT "admin_verifications".* FROM "admin_verifications" WHERE "admin_verifications"."type" = 10

puts Employment.joins(account: { profile: :verifications }).where("admin_verifications.type = ?", "career").to_sql
SELECT "employments".*
FROM "employments"
INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."id" = "employments"."account_id"
INNER JOIN "profiles" ON "profiles"."account_id" = "accounts"."id"
INNER JOIN "admin_verifications" ON "admin_verifications"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE (admin_verifications.type = 'career')
```

Answer (score 0):

こちら解決したので、回答として投稿します。
バージョンを上げたら直るそうです。

[Allow `where` references association names as joined table alias names by kamipo · Pull Request #40106 · rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40106)